# How to get back the redefined DPC method which redefinition was deleted?

Tags: abap, redefinition, sap-gateway

I have a DPC class in sap for a gateway service. I redefined a `getEntitySet` method and wrote some code in it.

Then I accidentally undid the redefinition and all my code is gone. Is there any way to get my code back?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get my code back?

Yes, unless you activated it. Just redefine it again and your former code will appear in the method automatically, you don't even need to go to Versions. If you see that method in the blue state, it is not yet activated.

[image]

If you deleted the redefinition and activated the method, this is the point of no return and you've lost the code forever. Undefinition does not cause automatic version generation.

However, you can prevent such situations to happen in future by making manual version generation. Just go to *Utilities->Versions->Generate version* after you implemented the method and that's it.

Now even (de)activation and (un)definition is not a problem for you, you'll always have YOUR version type U in the database.

[image]